# next li active triggers function

Tags: jquery, function, triggers, toggle

Basically, I have a function called "toggler" that changes the background and content of the site when an li trigger is active. That part of the site works perfect. I then added left and right directional `<a>` tags and this is where I'm scratching my head. I need these `<a>` tag triggers to call the toggler function and loop through all li without a gap in content. Right now on the last-child to first-child there is a gap between the content.

```
arrow_trigger: function() {
    $('#rightScroll').bind('click', function(e){

    // Determine current active - 
    if ($('li.toggle.active'))  
    {

        // If there's an active, next li a is passed to toggler.
    if ($('ul#menu li.active').length > 0)
    {
        // There's an active. yippidedooooo!!!!
        var next = $('ul#menu li.active').next('li').children('a');

        // If no next - default back to first.
        if (next.length > 0)
        {
                        SITE.toggler(next);

        } else {

            // No 'next'
            console.log('foo');
            SITE.toggler($(active).children('a'));
        }


    } else {

        // Default to first LI
        var active = $('ul#menu li:first-child');

        SITE.toggler($(active).children('a'));
    }

    // If active = last li - first li a is passed to toggler
    }   
    });

},
```

I'm hoping that I am making sense here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$('li.toggle.active')` will always return `true`, since an empty array `[]` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

To check to see if there are any active li's select on them, and check the length property.

```
if ($('li.toggle.active').length > 0)
```

Of do you want to check whether the li that contains the button that was clicked is active?

```
if ($(this).parent("li").hasClass("active"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam. I have the active state working and switching to the next li. However, my else statement of defaulting back to first li isn't working. Would you happen to know why?
`} else {
      
 // Default to first LI
 var active = $('ul.menu li:first-child');
       
 SITE.toggler($(active).children('a'));
}`

Comment: @slouey6 - not sure - can you set up a fiddle?